# Installing apps from the playstore without user intervention - Rooted device

Tags: android, android-intent, apk

Is there a way where I can use the application as superuser SU and download the app from the play store. Installation can be called by using .apk file path as below.

```
    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
.setData(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk"))
.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
 startActivity(promptInstall);
```

For this to happen I have to retrieve the .apk file which is on the play store. Is there any means to get the .apk file from the play store with out user intervention. The following intent brings me to the play store and shows the app page with 'install' button to be clicked.

```
  Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.package.name"));
  startActivity(goToMarket);
```

Comment: Please hire an attorney. Please have the attorney read [the Play Store Terms of Service](https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/about/play-terms.html). Please then discuss your plans with that attorney, so the attorney can give you advice as to the potential "civil or criminal liability" from those plans.

Comment: Alright you nailed it :)